# PBKDF2 - Unable to generate the same Base64-encoded key with Node and Java

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, pbkdf2

I am working on a project that features hand-rolled password hashing in Java, and am tasked with duplicating the hashing scheme in NodeJS in order to prevent users from having to reset their passwords.

I cannot seem to write a hashing function that generates an identical key to the one generated by the legacy code.

I've done some digging into the internals of each implementation, and I've identified a key difference in that the NodeJS version measures keyLength in bytes and the Java version uses bits. I've taken this into account with my current attempt, but am still having no luck.

The Java implementation:

```
public static String hash(byte[] salt, String password) throws HashException {
    try {
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        return encode(f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new HashException("Issues hashing the password", e);
    }
}
```

My attempt in NodeJS:

```
const crypto = require("crypto")

const encodedsalt = "oFoz+aZuGX5Ad/HAa35HLw=="
const encodedpass = "fp+gXqcO7fBKuXuhZQPY/A=="

// decode 
const decodedsalt = Buffer.from(encodedsalt, "base64")
const decodedpass = Buffer.from(encodedpass, "base64")

var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync("13111789", decodedsalt, 65536, 16, "sha1")
var encodedKey = key.toString("base64")
```

I expect the keys to match, because each implementation uses an identical byte array for the salt, and an identical string for the password. Instead, the keys match in length only. I'm certain that there is some quirk of the implementations that I am not noticing, but I can't see it! Any help appreciated - all other PBKDF2 questions focused on some other minor issue, so I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Please also add the used values for `salt` and `password` in the Java part.

Answer (score 1):

the code you posted is basically fine.  you've not defined `encode` in your Java code, so the problem might be there.  here's the Java code for a working example:

```java
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

public static String hash(byte[] salt, String password) throws Exception {
    SecretKeyFactory pbkdf2 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);
    byte[] secret = pbkdf2.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret);
}
```

this can be run as:

```java
String base64_salt = "oFoz+aZuGX5Ad/HAa35HLw==";
byte[] salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64_salt);

System.out.println(hash(salt, "13111789"));
```

giving me: `On7VbkKDXdz8aTWo5tDBXw==`

the equivalent JS code would be:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function hash(salt, password) {
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 65536, 16, "sha1");
    return key.toString("base64");
}
```

which can be run as:

```
const base64_salt = "oFoz+aZuGX5Ad/HAa35HLw==";
const salt = Buffer.from(base64_salt, "base64");

console.log(hash(salt, "13111789"));
```

also giving me: `On7VbkKDXdz8aTWo5tDBXw==`